# Theoretical Electron Bunching paper, variable question

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, particle-accelerators

What exactly is $\varphi$ referring to in this paper: [Electron bunchers for industrial RF linear accelerators: theory and design guide](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjp/s13360-021-01312-3)?

Specifically, within the context of this equation:

$$\frac{dW}{dz}=qE_z \cos\varphi \ \ ?$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but here is an intuitive explanation of bunching from FermiLab. Not at research paper level, but a useful explanation. [Accelerator Science: Why RF?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mu4m7wSnpD0&list=PLCfRa7MXBEsoJuAM8s6D8oKDPyBepBosS&index=54&t=6s)